# Cannot change wifi channel on Linux 3.6.11 with iw and kismet (device busy error)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, usb

I am dealing with a strange problem with wifi on my raspberry pi (I`m not sure if this has influence). I tried this with 3 different usb wifi devices. All of them are working perfectly if I connect to AP with wpa_supplicant. Troubles start when I start kismet (2011-03-R2) - I receive these error messages:

```
mac80211_setchannel() could not set channel 1/2412 on interface 'te0mon' err -25
```

The original name wifi interface name is te0, it`s configured in udev, I just needed to distinguish all my wifi devices. The same problem is with iw command:

```
iw te0 set channel 1
```

returns:

```
command failed: Device or resource busy (-16)
```

The device is down, not used by any other process (as far as I can recognize). These troubles started after upgrading to kernel 3.6.11 from 3.2.something (I don't remember this exactly). I can't downgrade it because other problems were solved by this. I even tried to download iw version 3.8 (the newest) and compatibility drivers 3.9 and it`s still the same.

Do you have any idea, what could be wrong? How to debug this (find, why the device is busy)?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try `iw te0 set freq 2412` ?

Comment: Thanks, but it`s still the same.

Comment: What is the current state of your vifs ? (`iw dev`). If there is both a managed and a monitor vif, remove the managed one and retry. `mac80211` assumes that monitor interfaces are slaves to other vifs if there is one.

Comment: If I delete the te0 interface, kismet server doesn't work at all, because there is no te0. I`ll try to configure kismet to use te0mon, but even if this helps, it won`t answer why `iw te0 set channel 1` doesn`t work.

Comment: setting the channel of a unconnected managed mode vif makes no sense when you think of it. a managed mode vif should either scan or use the channel specified via the AP's beacons.  If you want to monitor things, use only a monitor vif and set its channel/freq accordingly.

Comment: If you describe it in this way, it makes sense and it also actually helps - I need to create monitor interface, point kismet to it and delete the managed interface. It isn`t comfortable, but it works. Thank you

Comment: This thread really help me a lot. After install Ubuntu 14.04, I can't set channel/freq when do wlan capture, using aircrack-ng/iw/iwconfig are both useless. Thanks Pavel and BatchyX!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to BatchyX I have a solution:

- create minotor device
  `iw dev te0 interface add te0mon type monitor`
- delete managed te0 
  `iw dev te0 del`
- configure kismet to use te0mon
  `ncsource=te0mon:type=mac80211,name=te0mon`